# /usr/share/dotnet/sdks/microsoft.docker.sdk/sdk/sdk.props was not found

Tags: c#, linux, jenkins, msbuild, .net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WVCA.png)

hi friends

While exploring the dotnet core with Linux, jenkins and docker I've face the build issue which gives the error in title "/usr/share/dotnet/sdks/microsoft.docker.sdk/sdk/sdk.props was not found". Because of this build is getting failed.

I checked the  dotnet installation location to see that it was not available.

I know that this particular file will be available in this location on Windows with VS 2017 installed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\Sdk

how to get this installed or make it available on the linux box so that build can run smoothly.

PFA image which was run from the terminal for re-producing issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, see its [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6178) for details and updates. The problem is that a closed source component in VS is not part of the .net CLI.

The current workarounds are:

- Copy the `Microsoft.Docker.Sdk` folder from your VS installation to the CLI version you are using. For example from

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk
  ```

  into the folder

  ```
  /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Sdks/
  ```

  If the `Microsoft.Docker.Sdk` folder contains more than the `Sdk` subfolder, delete those other folders (e.g. `build`, `tools`).
- Create a second solution containing all projects except for the docker project (`.dcproj`) and only build that from the CLI.